# Instantly change button when value reaches 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I clicking the button the user HP goes down till 0 and then button changes. But what happens more is, when the  `userHealth` reaches zero the button did not change. You have to click one more time to button change. How to solve this ?

JS:

```
$(".attBtn").click(function() {

    var userId = 4;
    var attackdmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var userdmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var minimum = 0;    

    if(userHealth == 0){
        info.innerHTML = '<strong>'+user.textContent+'</strong> have been defeated.';
        attackBtn.css("backgroundColor", "blue");
        attackBtn.css("border", "none");
        innerAttBtn.innerHTML = "Get the reward <img src="+"/img/chest2.png"+"/> ";
        return false;           
    }else if(attackerHealth == 0){
        info.innerHTML = '<strong>You</strong> have been defeated.';
    }else if(attackerHealth == 0 && userHealth == 0){
        info.innerHTML = '<strong>DRAW FIGHT</strong>';
    }else{

    userHealth -= attackdmg;
    attackerHealth -= userdmg;

    document.getElementById('attackerBar').setAttribute("style","width:"+attackerHealth+"%");
    document.getElementById('userBar').setAttribute("style","width:"+userHealth+"%");

    $.ajax("/arena/fight-user/"+userId+"/attack/"+attackdmg+"/"+userdmg,
    {

    }); 

    if(userHealth < 0){userHealth = minimum;}
    if(attackerHealth < 0){attackerHealth = minimum;}

    userHp.innerHTML = '<strong>'+userHealth+'</strong>';
    attackerHp.innerHTML = '<strong>'+attackerHealth+'</strong>';

    info.innerHTML = '<strong>' +user.textContent+'</strong>' +' hit <strong>You</strong> with ' +userdmg+' dmg <br> ' + '<strong>You</strong> hit ' 
    +'<strong>'+user.textContent+'</strong>'+ ' with '+ attackdmg +' dmg';
}

});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: I am going to assume your usershealth is calculated with integers(no floating points or decimals). Would there be an easy way to add a quick check that if userHealth === 1, then change the button? That's assuming that every attack atleast inflicts 1 hp of damage. You could perhaps check for this at the very beginning of the click function, and change the button before any other code is executed. Just an idea, as I haven't looked over the code too much, but seems like you are just suffering from some logic issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a logical flaw.
The reason, why you have to click once more, is because you declare what should happen at 0 HP **before** the HP gets actually to zero.

### The solution

put this

```
userHealth -= attackdmg;
attackerHealth -= userdmg;
if(userHealth < 0){userHealth = minimum;}
if(attackerHealth < 0){attackerHealth = minimum;}
```

before this

```
if(userHealth == 0){
...
```